# Method returning one index of an array throws NullPointer

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, return

When working on a program for school, I created a method which returned the index of an array based on the value you gave the method. The method throws a NullPointerException but in every index of the array has already been instantiated. To show this, I created a test program which does the same thing.

```
public class Test {
private static Number[] numbers = new Number[16];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

public Test() {
    for (Number n : numbers) {
        n = new Number(0);
    }
    System.out.println(get(0).value);
}

public Number get(int index) {
    return numbers[index];
}

class Number {
    public int value;

    public Number(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When run this should print the value of the Integer "value", in this case of the object in the first position of the array.

I am sure there is a simple explanation to this, but I am unaware of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop for read-only passes. Currently, in your constructor, the elements in your array still remain uninitialized and hence the error.

So change it to a normal for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    numbers[i] = new Number(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you immensely! I had no idea the for each loop did not act exactly like the regular for loop.

Comment: @piechesse Yes, you can read the link I provided, particulary at the end ;)